# Best way to apply arguments of mixed, possibly Applicative, types to a function

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm fairly new to Haskell and functional programming and I have recently been learning about Functors, Applicatives and Monads. While I seem to understand the basics, I have trouble figuring out the best/most idiomatic way apply function arguments when the type of some arguments changes to an Applicative. Consider the following, simple code:

```
myfun :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
myfun a b c = a + b + c             -- lets pretend this does something more complicated

a = 5
b = 10
c = 20

result = myfun a b c
```

Using `myfun` to calculate the result is fairly straightforward. However, as our requirements change, our inputs `a`, `b` and `c` may change to be i.e. `Maybe Int` or `[Int]` rather then `Int`. We can still use our unmodified `myfun` by doing one of the following:

```
result = myfun <$> a <*> b <*> c   -- either like this
result = liftA3 myfun a b c        -- or like that
```

However, in practice the arguments `a`, `b` and `c` may not always end up to be inside the same Applicative, and thus the two methods mentioned above would not work. What is the best way to still make the `myfun` function work without modifying it? Consider the following scenarios for `a`, `b` and `c`:

- Some are `Int`, some are `Maybe Int` (result of the application would be `Maybe Int`)
- Some are `Maybe Int`, some are `Either String Int` (result could be `Maybe Int` or `Either String Int`, with the semantics of short-circuiting the calculation if any argument is `Nothing` or `Left`)
- Some are `[Int]`, some are `Maybe Int` (result should be `Maybe [Int]`, with the semantics of calculating all possible combinations as if all arguments were `[Int]`, then wrapping that inside a `Just`, unless on of the Maybies are `Nothing`, in which case we short-circuit to `Nothing`)

Any insights are very much appreciated!

Comment: One way could be defining [a Multi Parameter Type Class](https://wiki.haskell.org/Multi-parameter_type_class) which holds the `myfun` function. Then you have to write a separate instance per possible input types. You may or may not need to use instance only pragmas like [`{-# OVERLAPPING #-}`, `{-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}`, `{-# OVERLAPS #-}` or `{-# INCOHERENT #-}`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overlapping-instances).

Comment: @Aiueiia What exactly do you want `myfun` to do when given three different `Applicative`s? There may not necessarily be a way to do what you want in a consistent manner. (e.g. what would you do when given an `IO Int`, `Const String Int`, `Either Bool Int`?)

Comment: Can you give examples of an intended use? I'm having a hard time figuring out what you might want the result of `myfun` to be when applied to, say, `2`, `Just 3` and `Right 4`. Similarly if you replace that last one with a `Left` value. (Just realised @bradrn has already asked essentially this :) Will leave this here for clarity though.)

Comment: @bradrn I guess you might be right in stating no consistent/general solution is possible or would make sense. My intuition is that we need to 'elevate' all arguments to be the same applicative (which is doable for my 1st example with pure/return, some function Maybe Int -> Either String Int for the 2nd example, no idea for the 3rd though). Alternatively there might be some other concepts or useful transformation functions similar to liftXX which I don't yet know about (remember I'm new to Haskell). I modified the question to better explain the examples.

Comment: (1/3) @Aiueiia I’m not too confident with this area, but you may be interested in natural transformations: functions of the form `forall x. f x -> g x`. It should be pretty easy to write a function like `liftA3Multi :: Applicative f => (forall x. g x -> f x) -> (forall x. h x -> f x) -> (x -> y -> z -> r) -> f x -> g y -> h z -> f r`, but then you don’t get to directly use the `Applicative` structure of `g` and `h`, since they both get converted to `f` first.

Comment: (2/3) Alternately, since `Applicative`s compose, I feel it should be possible to extend @danidiaz’s answer to make a function `liftA3Multi' :: (Applicative f, Applicative g, Applicative h) => (x -> y -> z -> r) -> f x -> g y -> h z -> f (g (h r)))`, where you lift `f x`, `g y` and `h z` to `Compose f (Compose g h r)`, and then do [`getCompose`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-15.13/base-4.13.0.0/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose) to get back the nested type. This feels like the most general version, although it may be inconvenient to deal with the nested `Applicative`s it returns.

Comment: (3/3) (And of course the result depends on the order in which you nest the `Applicative`s.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you want to happen. There may not be any universal way to combine different monads. In general, you can often (always?) use a monad transformer when you truly need to combine different monads, but usually there are simpler solutions. That's the case with the specific combinations you mention.

In all of these specific cases, you can transform one of the monads into another. In the following, I'll give some examples of ways this could be done.

Some of these examples use functions from `Data.Maybe`, so I'll start with:

```
import Data.Maybe
```

It's not required in the first example, but will be in the second and third.

## Some `Int`, some `Maybe Int`

If you have a combination of `Int` and `Maybe Int` values, the solution is straightforward. Just elevate the `Int` values to `Maybe Int`. You can use `Just` or `pure` for this. Here's an example using `pure`:

```
a1 = 5
b1 = Just 10
c1 = 20

result1 :: Maybe Int
result1 = myfun <$> pure a1 <*> b1 <*> pure c1
```

The result is `Just 35`.

## Some `Maybe Int`, some `Either String Int`

You can repeat the trick with transforming one of the monads into the other. You can transform `Maybe Int` values to `Either String Int` values if you have a good `String` to use for `Nothing` cases. You can also transform `Either String Int` values to `Maybe Int` values by throwing away the `String` values.

Here's an example that transforms `Maybe Int` to `Either String Int`:

```
a2 = Just 5
b2 = Right 10
c2 = Left "Boo!"

result2 :: Either String Int
result2 = myfun <$> maybe (Left "No value") Right a2 <*> b2 <*> c2
```

This combination uses the `maybe` function from `Data.Maybe`. The result is `Left "Boo!"`.

## Some `[Int]`, some `Maybe Int`

You can easily turn `Maybe Int` into `[Int]` using `maybeToList`:

```
a3 = [5, 10]
b3 = Nothing
c3 = Just 20

result3 :: [Int]
result3 = myfun <$> a3 <*> maybeToList b3 <*> maybeToList c3
```

The result of doing this is `[]` because `Nothing` transforms to `[]`, and that's how `Applicative` works for lists. This may not be what you want, but I hope these examples can inspire you to come up with the compositions you'd like.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in other answers, here perhaps it doesn't make much sense to preserve the distinctions between the `Applictative`s, it would be better to reduce them to a single one before applying them to `myfun`.

But sometimes it is convenient to preserve the distinctions. The good news is that [`Applicative`s compose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZ9FpG8May8&feature=youtu.be&t=370), meaning that the "nesting" of two or more `Applicative`s can always be given an `Applicative` instance.

For example, we could define a combined `Applicative` like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia, TypeOperators #-}
import Data.Functor.Compose

newtype A a = A (Either String (Maybe [a]))
    deriving (Functor,Applicative) 
         via Either String `Compose` Maybe `Compose` []
```

We are using [`-XDerivingVia`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia) in our own auxiliary datatype to avoid having to work with nested [`Compose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose) newtypes, which would be a bit more cumbersome.

`Applicative` composition works "from the outer layer inwards". That is, if there's a `Left` somehwere, all the computation ends with a `Left`. If the outer layer succeeds, then we combine the inner `Maybe`s, and if they all turn to be `Just`, we applicatively combine the inner lists.

We also need some tedious boilerplate: injection functions into our combined `Applicative`:

```
liftL1 :: Either String a -> A a
liftL1 = A . fmap (pure . pure)

liftL2 :: Maybe a -> A a
liftL2 = A . pure . fmap pure

liftL3 :: [a] -> A a
liftL3 = A . pure . pure
```

Putting it to work:

```
a = Right 5
b = Just 10
c = [20]

result = liftA3 myfun (liftL1 a) (liftL2 b) (liftL3 c)
```

Or, using [`-XApplicativeDo`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=applicativedo#extension-ApplicativeDo):

```
result = do
    a <- liftL1 $ Right 5
    b <- liftL2 $ Just 10
    c <- liftL3 $ [20]
    pure $ myfun a b c
```